# Pay pal -Pay with credit card only remove pay with paypal account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a requirement to make `PayPal` payment options configurable.For some cases customer should pay only through the `PayPal` account(hide credit card option) and some other cases customer should pay only through the credit cards(Hide pay with `PayPal` option).
So I have to enable and disable one at a time.

Currently I have both options in my application .
I can able to hide credit card option by setting `solution type = MARK`.But how can I able to hide Pay with `PayPal` account option?

Any one can help me  on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `LANDINGPAGE` = Billing , the `Pay with PayPal account` will be hidden.
If you set `LANDINGPAGE` = Login, the credit card option will be hidden

[Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

It is not possible to remove "pay with PayPal" option in Express checkout. You can do this in different Product such as [Website Payment PRO](https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_wp-pro-overview-outside), [Payflow Gateway](https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-overview-outside).

Comment: Currently my application using 'solution type = MARK'and 'LANDINGPAGE = Billing' this will not hide 'Pay with PayPal' option

Comment: but this will collapse 'Pay with PayPal'.Any other way to remove 'Pay with PayPal' option and allow only 'credit card' option?

Comment: No, it is not possible to remove "pay with PayPal" option in Express checkout. You can do this in different Product such as Website Payment PRO,Payflow Gateway.